# Confused by pygame key.get_pressed() method

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a bit confused with the method `key.get_pressed()`

So I have checked the **pygame website**, and it says that the method will `"returns a sequence of boolean values representing the state of every key on the keyboard.....and use the key constant values to index the array"`.

I saw people writting codes like:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
       ......
```

Here is the question: `pygame.key.get_pressed()` actually returns a tuple, so how can people use a bracket to index the value? I mean it should be like `"tuple[sequence]"`, right?

Comment: Tuples are indexed by integers. Is the key constant an integer?

Comment: `pygame.K_LEFT` is a constant and represents a well defined number respectively index. In `pygame`, there exists the declaration `K_LEFT = 276`. See [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) and [`pygame.locals`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html#module-pygame.locals). `print(pygame.K_LEFT)` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button.

In Python the elements of lists and tuples can be accessed by [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-subscription).
In the code of your of your question

> ```py
> keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
> if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
>       .....
> ```

`pygame.K_LEFT` is a constant and represents a well defined number respectively index. In pygame, there *exists* the declaration `K_LEFT = 276` (Do `print(pygame.K_LEFT)` to see what I mean). See also [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) and [`pygame.locals`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html#module-pygame.locals).
Hence the expression `keys[pygame.K_LEFT]` retrieves the element (value) associated with `pygame.K_LEFT`.